# InputText bottom border disappears automatically all of sudden

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm seeing InputText bottom border disappears automatically all of sudden. If I restart the application in the simulator, then I see the border again. Then suddenly it disappears when I make some change which pushes hot-reload in the simulator. I'm 100% sure, it was not because of my changes because if I simply restart the app in the simulator, i see the bottom border again. I'm using RN 0.30 and android simulator. Anybody know what's happening? Please see picture below. [image]

```
       <TextInput
          placeholder="Title"
          style={styles.inputField}
          placeholderTextColor={theme.placeholderTextColor}
          maxLength={50}
          returnKeyType={'next'}
          ref={(c) => { this._fieldTitle = c; }}
          value={title}
          onFocus={() => {
            this.inputFocused(this._fieldTitle);
            this.setState({ showTitleLabel: true });
          }}
          onChangeText={(title) => this.setState({ title })}
          onEndEditing={this._validateTitle}
          onBlur={() => {
            if (title === null || title === '') {
              this.setState({ showTitleLabel: false });
            }
          }}
        />
```

Comment: Please share the code for rendering the InputText.

Comment: @vijayst added the code

Comment: onBlur uses title. Where is it defined? what does showTitleLabel do? Is the bottom border computed based on some state?

Comment: title is from state. showTitleLabel is flag in state based on the value, the label for the input is shown or hidden.  bottom border  is not computed. I'm even setting the border bottom styles. It's the default border bottom style.